# Unity crash after working on animation and ragdoll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, crash

(Reposting because first one didn't get any answers)

So the way the story goes, is that I was working on a new human prefab in unity, which had improved weight painting and came with some animations (the old model had none). What I did was I put them all in an animator attached to my human gameobject (in the animation controller, obviously). I think the reason I got crashed is that it might have tried to do two animations at once but I'm not sure. The other thing is, I was making a ragdoll for the new model and copy-pasting all the values for the rigidbody, character joint, and collider from the old model to the new model. I don't think anything went wrong here since it worked just fine with the old model, and it's not like it would make this much of an error even if all the values were wrong, but I don't know. The last two things were the human script I attached to the new model (copy-pasted values, once again) (this script controls the animator parameters) and navmesh (copy-pasted also). I also had a script on my pelvis object that controls when the ragdoll is active, which is when the human dies.

The problem is that every time I open up the scene, unity always crashes and gives me a bug reporter pop-up. If I go to a different scene through my files it works fine, so I narrowed down the issue to the specific scene. I also tried making a copy of all my game files and deleting all the files in the assets (animation, scripts, prefabs, etc.) but it's still crashing.

My question is what is going on and how do I fix it?

If you need any more information, I'll do my best to give it with the limitation that Unity is crashing. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this because the project is very important to me. Also nothing in the temp folder is going to help because I relaunched unity right after the crash, so the only thing there is the UnityLockFile and workerlic files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!!!

i just updated my unity version lol

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)